# Image rotate background js jumps to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with javascript that I don't know how to solve. First of all I am a total newb in this. I found a code that loads random images in div element and tweaked it a little bit (original code loaded images in order - I inserted a type of algorithm for randomness (pretty clumsy but it somehow works and rarely repeats the same image one after another).

Now the code works just fine, but when I **scroll** for e.g. to **the bottom** of my page the instant moment that **script loads** a new image into div element **browser jumps to the top of the page**.

How to stop this from happening? Please help me with a 'child language'(because as I told, I'm a total newb in js).

Thank you all in advance for your time!

```
<script src="js_vrt/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  var images = ['img_vrt/pozadine/1p.jpg', 'img_vrt/pozadine/2p.jpg', 'img_vrt/pozadine/3p.jpg', 'img_vrt/pozadine/4p.jpg'];
  var image = $('#pozad');
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length) + 0);
  var ist;
  //Initial Background image setup
  image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
  //Change image at regular intervals
  setInterval(function() {

    image.fadeOut(1500, function() {
      image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i++] + ')');
      image.fadeIn(1500);
    });
    if (i == images.length)
      i = Math.floor((Math.random() * (images.length - 1)) + 0);
    else i = Math.floor((Math.random() * (images.length)) + 0);
  }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post a link to see the issue on a real environment?

Comment: ...I actually managed to solve it! ~ The div element that has the changing background MUST be contained in another wrapping div (which has the same height). This way there is no jumping over the page!

Comment: So the problem was not in js, it was in HTML structure. Thank you all for reading! Hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I figured out:

Problem is not in the js code. It is in HTML structure.

If someone has the same problem where screen jumps to top of the page while loading images do the following:

The div element that has the changing background MUST be contained in another wrapping div (which has the same height).

```
<div id="wrap_element">
    <div id="div_that_loads_the_images"></div>
</div>
```